# IN clause is not working properly in MYSQL php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql query like this

```
$statusData = $DB->get_records_sql("SELECT id, element, value FROM {scorm_scoes_track} WHERE scormid = ? AND userid = ? AND element =$DB->get_in_or_equal('cmi.core.lesson_status','cmi.core.total_time')", array($scorm_id, $userid) );
```

So i am trying to fetch the values from query

```
<?php
$statusData = reset($statusData); 
 if($statusData->element == 'cmi.core.lesson_status') 
$status = $statusData->value ; 
elseif($statusData->element == 'cmi.core.total_time') 
 $totaltimes = $statusData->value ;
```

but its just showing only status value..it's not showing total time value..Can any one help me

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is this moodle?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any `in` operator in your code, so there is nothing that could work at all as an `in`!

Replace the `=` with `in` and remove the moodle call as well as shown below:

```
...AND element IN ('cmi.core.lesson_status','cmi.core.total_time')
```

Comment: You do not need the moodle call either.

Comment: its repeating the loop like this Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( )

Comment: Then you have some other issue with your code that is not related to what you have described and shared with us.

Comment: when i use like that only one value is working either status or total time only one is working..both are not working t the same time

Comment: This is how it works in sql. Again, if it does not work for you, then the issue is somewhere else and we cannot help with that because we do not have any information.